# The Meaning of Understand

Tags: meaning

I'm working on a programming project with the main focus of 'understanding'. I'm fully aware of the technical implications but that's not why I'm here. I need to know what 'to understand' actually means, since all of the definitions I've found so far have been either circular or vague.

I'm posting because this is beyond my brain power alone and I'm a programmer not a linguist.

Put simply: What I'm asking for is a definition of understanding that doesn't invoke it or its synonyms.

An example of what I don't want:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/understanding
Which points to:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprehension
Which just points back to understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "actually means"? How would you say what the following words actually mean: "know", "freedom", "cow"? It's more or less the same problem.

Comment: "To understand" means to have a theory about.

Comment: Updated for clarity

Comment: @TeamEnderzFTW *Understanding* is the opposite of the feeling you're having right now about the word "understanding". It's the feeling you're hoping to experience by getting the kind of answer you're seeking, and then the ongoing relationship that answer would create for you with the word "understanding".

Comment: Thanks for the 'definition', however I think you missed the fact that it's circular.

Comment: @TeamEnderzFTW It is not at all circular. It points to an exact, visceral experience you are having right now, a concrete, on-the-ground sensation, as well as defining it in terms of *something you want*, which you therefore already have a conception of. You're saying "I have this gnawing, empty feeling in my stomach, and I think it would be ameliorated by eating something" and hen asking "What is hunger? What is satiation?". I'm telling you what you are feeling is hunger, and what you are desiring is satiation. It's not circular at all, I'm helping you attach a label to an experience. [cont]

Comment: [cont] In other words: it's the very definition of "definition". It functions in the same way the dictionary helps you link labels to experiences with e.g. definitions like "red is the color of blood". There is no better way to define things, unless you've found a loophole in the Münchhausen trilemma. All definitions are either infinite regresses (toddler style "but why? but why? but why?"), or circular in the sense that worries you here ("understanding" -> "comprehension" -> "understanding"), or based on axioms. The core human axioms are lived experiences.)

Comment: @DanBron, You're talking about a feeling of understanding, not understanding itself.  You can have a sensation of understanding without actually understanding. (Actual understanding is not just having a theory, but having a correct theory.)

Comment: @GregLee Justified true belief is knowledge, not understanding. Or do you think this question is just epistemological under the covers? If so, it's probably way too broad.

Comment: @DanBron, But I didn't say above that understanding was having a correct theory -- just having a theory.  So I don't see how "justified" and "true" come into it.  Also, I say nothing about how you come by a theory, or how you judge whether it's correct, so there is no element of epistemology in my characterization.

Comment: @GregLee I can't reconcile two statements, the first from your first comment: *actual understanding is not just having a theory, but having a correct theory* and the second from your most recent comment: *but I didn't say above that understanding was having a correct theory -- just having a theory*. Help me out? Anyway, what I was pointing to with my earlier comments is essentially identical to the lines user6726 is drawing in the (currently) sole answer: *A non-circular account ... is built on other well-defined concepts which ultimately are based in perception*.

Comment: @DanBron, I proposed that understanding means having a theory and that actual understanding was having a correct theory, but I did not say that understanding was having a correct theory.  Is that unclear?  I didn't take the original question to be about word usage.  I was proposing a theory about what understanding is, rather than trying to characterize when it is appropriate to use that word.  I assume we all know English here.

Comment: @GregLee If the OP is asking about understanding, then I think we should constrain ourselves to that topic. If the OP is asking about "actual understanding", then this question is simply a proxy for epistemology, which is too broad to cover in a single answer, and in any case is confusingly framed. So let's talk only about "understanding". In terms of "we all understand English", I think that's not the question, but a question of 'what does the symbol `understanding` refer to'? Which is the only philosophical question which makes sense to try to answer with a dictionary, as OP did.

Comment: I agree with Greg; if you have a theory that you accept as an explanation for something, then you would say you understand it. Whether you're correct is irrelevant to whether you have experienced understanding.

Comment: @jlawler If that is your position, then you agree with me, too :) The question then remains if be sensation or experiencing of having understood something suffices as a definition of "underatanding" and therefore answers OP's question. In other words: did you upvote user6726's answer? If so (as, being a linguist, I suspect you did), then you and I are on the same page wrt this question, and have no disagreements about either the question or the appropriate answer.

Comment: _Understanding_ has a number of 'meanings'. _My understanding of this is `S`_, for example, refers not to an experience but to a resultant conclusion; but _Understanding PDEs is helpful but not required for the job_ refers to a state of understanding, and _Understanding what your partner wants can take a long time to learn_ refers to a process of change in understanding. I would hesitate to undertake a computational evaluation of a concept so ill-defined and context-sensitive.

Comment: @DanBron, you say "I think that's not the question, but a question of 'what does the symbol understanding refer to'?"  Maybe so, but that is not how I took it.  I thought it was about understanding, rather than what the symbol 'understanding' refers to.

Comment: @GregLee For me, "about understanding" and "about what the symbol 'understanding' refers to" are identical and indistinguishable questions. But then again, I'm unversed and naive when it comes to philosophy.

Comment: @DanBron, I don't think that can be right.  A chipmunk hears a loud crackling sound in the forest, and scampers off away from the sound, because he understands that there is a forest fire.  It has nothing to do what a symbol refers to, because no symbols are involved.  How can you have a good account of understanding if you deny understanding to the advanced animals -- dogs, cats, horses -- which do not have symbolic language?

Comment: @GregLee, are you saying that a chipmunk has a theory of the existence of forest fires (and how does the sound enter in to it)? That stretches the concept "theory", and its connection to understanding – what does it mean to "have a theory". Alternatively, chipmunks don't understand anything.

Comment: @user6726, yes, though he might not put it that way.

Comment: @Dan-Bron The loop hole in the dilemma: fixpoints! Obviously, circular reasoning is infinite; An axiom can be circular on itself, which makes it a fixpoint. I'm spotty about the details, but think about it from the other side: Do you really finish all your thinking once and for all? The meat of an axiomatic theory is to have axioms that are natural, I guess, reflected in the mechanics of our brain. That's why Descartes' *cogito ergo sum* was such a great insight. Ironically, I'm on the fence if your play satisfied, whether *I know that I don't know* is axiomatic, or that the askee didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not clear what fact of "understand" you want, because you haven't given us a definition of "meaning" (asking for "actual meaning" just confuses the matter, since it implies that there are non-actual meanings that you don't want). Here are some notions of "meaning" that I think you might be interested in. (1) a translation matrix into other languages or the same language, e.g. "understand": "comprehend": "comprendre": "fahamu": "vorstå". (2) an reduction to defined terms of the states and events which are described by the word, in normative usage. (3) a statistically-adjusted reduction to defined terms of the states and events which are described by the word, in observed usage by all speakers of English. (1) is usually just wrong, and seems to be the thing you don't want. (3) is too complicated and is of dubious empirical value (sampling problems, for example). I surmise that you want something like (2), where you state the necessary and sufficient conditions for felicitously using "understand" in Standard English.

A non-circular account would distinguish "understand" from every other word (unless you have a situation like "sofa" and "couch" where there is no difference referents), and is built on other well-defined concepts which ultimately are based in perception. Only a consciousness can "understand", and what the consciousness understands is a fact of reality. This does not distinguish "understand" from "think" or "know", but you can add more distinguishing features, so that you can differentiate "understand" from "know". To do that, you could assemble pairs of sentences which differ in word choice, like "I know Spanish" and "I understand Spanish", which should lead you to see some differences in the situations described by the two verb – you may understand Spanish yet hardly be able to speak it, but it would be infelicitous usage to say say that you know Spanish if you can't speak it. Similarly, the situations described by saying "I know Jack" and "I understand Jack" are different, though there is some intersection. If you apply these two verbs to somewhat different objects, the difference becomes sharper: you can say "I understand this contract" but it is almost senseless to say "I know this contract" – unless you mean "I have encountered this contract before".

It appears, then, that you are looking for a characterization of how "understand" is distinguished from all other words of English, in terms of felicitous usage. Since you mentioned being a programmer, it is likely that you are not interested only in "literal meaning", you would also be interested in metaphorical extensions. When A says to B "We understand each other", A is not just saying that A literally understands B and vice versa, he is saying that they are in agreement (so B could respond "I understand your position, but I don't think we *do* agree"). It depends on the nature of the programming task, but it is likely that it will have to deal with "actual usage", which expands the range of situations that have to be dealt with substantially. So while I encourage approach (2), from a practical perspective, ignoring "actual usage" (figurative language, especially) may be a short-sighted and mistaken choice.

Comment: "actual" could be benevolently interpreted as "effective" in the electric sense, that is an averaged analogy instead of a back and forth (quite literally, regarding the MW's definition). Funny enough, "mean" can mean the same thing, a median that mediates the central element of the word. In that sense, I guess, "-der-" is the central element. I'm joking. I'm trying to say a comparative historical analysis of the term and related concepts would go a long way to expose the central idea, unless there was a break somewhen. The goal is to dismount levels of abstraction, down to actionable commands.

Comment: Your points 1, 2 and 3 actually describe what it means to understand something, pretty well. 2 and 3 are parts of the scientific method. 1 is the hypothesis and subject to the conclusion, but the matrix relates phrases from a single language. *Language* in mathematical logic is building a *theory*: a set of symbols and statements about their relations. These relations can be encoded as operations in matrices as well (but I'm not too knowledgeable about that). According to a sying that I would love to find a source: In general, there are three ways to learn, by observation, by trial or insight